# Dynamically assign Google Analytics data to dataframes and name variables accordingly

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm using [rga](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga) to make API requests from Google Analytics. At the moment, I'm manually assigning the returned data to variables (e.g. `website1.topPages <- ga$getData(id,start.date=...`).

While this works, I'm generating quite a few tables and would love to cut down potential user error in naming variables. As such, I want to pass `website1` and the desired name of the dataset, make the API request, and end up with the dataframe assigned to `website1.**desiredName**`. Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Why are you creating new variables. Why not just make `website1` a list and add new elements to that list via `website1[["desiredName"]]`. That would make things much easier.

Comment: Can you store a dataframe inside of a list? (Forgive me, I'm still relatively new to all of this). If so, that sounds like a home-run.

Comment: Absolutely you can. Lists can pretty much hold anything.

Comment: @MrFlick Follow-up question: I'm dealing with an account with a large number of sites/properties, and each needs its own reporting data. While adding each dataframe to lists is working well, how would I pass the site name as the list name?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the problem. You can have lists of lists of you need an additional level of grouping. It may be better to open a new question with a full description of the problem.